# Application error custom texts and buttons without Oracle Apex texts

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to set application error custom texts and custom buttons without Oracle Apex texts? For example I using `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20111, :APP_USER);`, Apex displays "ORA-20111: *'name'*
Contact your application administrator. Details about this incident are available via debug id "49020".", but I want to display *name*, *Text*, *URL*, without "Contact your application administrator...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dedicated [error handling function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmdb/managing-application-attributes.html#GUID-B744BE26-69B6-4084-A217-114CF05A5A4B)

And example is also found in the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.html#GUID-2CD75881-1A59-4787-B04B-9AAEC14E1A82)

I've demonstrated another customisation [here](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/09/enhance-oracle-apex-error-handling-function-logger.html)